# Prove that the height swept by the ball in the last second is $5 m/s$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, free-fall

I was studying kinematics and came across the following observation: every ball thrown upward with a speed greater than or equal to $ 10m/s $ will travel 5m in the last second of movement to maximum height. But I want proof on this.
My approach:

Distance travelled in $n^{th}$ second is calculated by:
$$d_n = v_0 + \frac{a}{2}(2n-1)$$
So:
$$5= v_0 - 5(2n-1)$$

$$v_0 = 10n$$

Would this be enough?

Comment: what about the units?

Comment: International system of units

Comment: @Elskrt the formula really should be as $d_n =v_0 (1s)- 5(1s)(2t-1)$, but its most of the time assumed that such is the case.

Comment: The formula is $d_n= v_0 + \frac{a}{2}(2n-1)$, it is possible to prove directly from the time subtraction of the time between $ n-1 $ and $ n $.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of attacking this problem:

The vertical motion is symmetric with respect to time about the high point.  The last second of rising is a mirror image of the first second of falling.

If you happen to notice the ball just as it reaches the high point and starts to fall back, how far will it fall from rest in one second?

How fast must you throw the ball to have it reach the high point from the previous answer?